# Class List<Map> cannot be converted to Collection<objects>

Tags: java, list, generics, collections

It may be a really stupid question , I have a java code which is as follows :

```
public Collection<Object> getCollection(){
     List<Map<String,Object> listMap = getListMap();
     return listMap;
}
```

I am getting an exception saying

```
cannot assign a value of Java.util.list<java.util.map<java.lang.String,java.lang.Object>>  
to java.util.Collection<java.lang.Object>
```

Of course the error must be valid , But why is that ? And how can i overcome this ?

Comment: A `Collection<Object>` can have any `Object` put into it. A `List<Map>` can only have maps put into it. You can get it to compile just by casting away the generics, but it really depends what you're trying to do.

Comment: have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2745265/2764279) question.

Comment: Java's generic types does not follows inheritance rules

Comment: This error seems not matching with the exposed code. I would expect to  "cannot convert..." but not "cannot assign"

Comment: Okay , I am very weak in generics ideally from my understanding this would have worked. Anyways , i will cast it for now. Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is List<Dog> a subclass of List<Animal>? Why aren't Java's generics implicitly polymorphic?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicitly-p)

Answer (score 1):

When using generics, avoid using references to `Object`. Instead use the wild card `?` For example, in your case, change the `Collection<Object>` to `Collection<?>`.

So your method becomes,

```
public Collection<?> getCollection(){
     List<Map<String,Object>> listMap = getListMap();
     return listMap;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

change your method signature to `Collection<Map<String,Object>>`

```
 public Collection<Map<String,Object>> getCollection(){
     List<Map<String,Object>> listMap = getListMap();
     return listMap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This Material will be useful for understanding generics Inheritance: 
[Java Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/inheritance.html)
.
Try this (it should work fine):

```
public Collection<Object> getCollection() {
    return new ArrayList<>(getListMap());
}
```